# Any KeePass-compatible password manager with OneDrive support?

Tags: software-recommendation, password, cloud, keepass

I am moving some desks from Windows and macOS to Ubuntu... yey! But I have a tiny problem: Some of these need to access KeePass v2 databases hosted in OneDrive.

Microsoft does not deliver OneDrive to Linux (to access the databases locally), and I do not find any KeePass v2 compatible app with support for OneDrive cloud file service.

Any clue to workaround it?

Thanks a lot and regards

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, Onedriver solves everything!

Github: https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver

OpenSUSE Build Service: https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Ajstaf&package=onedriver (it's useful for noobs like me)

Comment: I would have liked to see which release you tested & it worked for you on... If I needed to use it for my release; knowing what you used & where you found it worked is helpful details I feel.   (*Thanks for sharing your find though; upvoted for that detail anyway!*)